# How to write result from multiple tables to single table in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I want to write result to single table by selecting columns from multiple tables.
I want to achieve something like below in hive.

```
SELECT Table0.num,Table1.field1, Table2.field2, Table3.field3, Table4.field4
FROM Table0
FULL OUTER JOIN Table1 ON Table0.num = Table1.num
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table0.num = Table2.num
FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table0.num = Table3.num
FULL OUTER JOIN Table4 ON Table0.num = Table4.num
```

Please suggest how should I achieve this in hive?

When I am trying to execute above query in hive I am getting following exception.

FAILED: ParseException line 2:11 cannot recognize input near '' 'on' 'Table0' in select expression

Answer (score 1):

If I create a bunch of tables like this:

```
create table Table0(num int, Field0 int);
create table Table1(num int, Field1 int);
create table Table2(num int, Field2 int);
create table Table3(num int, Field3 int);
create table Table4(num int, Field4 int);
```

Then run the query you post it works just fine.

```
OK
Time taken: 38.26 seconds
```

What version of hive are you running? Is it possible the query was modified before posting on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `GROUP BY` if you are just selecting columns from multiple tables without aggregating. You could also use  `SELECT DISTINCT` (instead of the `GROUP BY`) if you don't want to have duplicate rows.

Comment: When I try to execute above query in hive throws parsing failed exception.

Comment: Could you update the question with more details including the full error message, table definitions, etc...